# Proof of an inequality involving a sum of squared differences and a max

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do you know if this a known inequality?

$t_{max}^2 \ge \sum_{i=1}^N {(t_i-\bar t)^2}$

where:

$\bar t = \frac 1 {N} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^N {t_i}$

and:

$t_{max} = \max t_i, i \in [1,N]$

And if not, do you think it is true? (it is in some numerical simulations I ran).
And if it is true, how would you go about proving it?
I attempted several expansions and simplifications, but I always got stuck :(

Thanks!

---

**EDIT** missing specification on the sign of $t_i$.

$t_i \ge 0, \forall i \in [1,N]$

---

**EDIT 2** numerical tests (R script)

```
set.seed(122333)
df <- expand.grid(N = 2:10, tmax = runif(9*10,1,100))
df["tmax_sq"] <- (df$tmax)^2

df["ts"] <- NA
df["tmean"] <- NA
df["sum_sq_diffs"] <- NA

for (r in 1:nrow(df)) {
  #ts <- runif(df[[r,"N"]], 0, df[[r,"tmax"]])
  ts <- c(0,runif(df[[r,"N"]]-1, 0, df[[r,"tmax"]]))
  tmean <- mean(ts)
  df[r,"ts"] <- paste(sort(ts), collapse = ",")
  df[r,"tmean"] <- tmean
  df[r,"sum_sq_diffs"] <- sum((ts-tmean)^2)
}

df["difference"] <- df$tmax_sq - df$sum_sq_diffs

plot(df$tmax_sq, df$sum_sq_diffs, col = df$N, pch = 16)
abline(0,1)
text(df$tmax_sq, df$sum_sq_diffs, col = df$N, label = as.character(df$N), pos = 4, cex = 0.7)

boxplot(difference ~ N, df, col = df$N)
abline(h=0)
```

It looks like the inequality is often, but indeed not always, true, and at least in this example it seems to be false more often when $N$ is larger.

To give you some context, this actually has important consequences on our work, as it's related to the choice of how to run an in vitro assay so that a given parameter is measured with the smallest possible error (given some constraints on the resources we can use).

The current theory was that running the assay in duplicate at two extreme time points ($0$ and $t_{max}$) was better than running it once at multiple points in that interval, always including $0$ and $t_{max}$.
The inequality I mentioned here is related to the comparison of the standard deviations on the parameter we are measuring in those two cases.
[In theory, to use the same resources in the two cases, we should have $N = 4$].

Thanks again to all those who contributed!

Comment: Are the $t_i$ positive ?

Comment: if not, taking $t_i = (-1)^i$ disproves the statement

Comment: for positive $t_i$, we have $2N {t_{max}}^2 \ge \sum_{i=1}^N (t_i - \bar t)^2$

Comment: For positive $t_i$ I guess we can even improve that: First notice that 
$$\overline{t} \leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} t_{\max} = t_{\max}.$$

If $t_i > 0$ for $i = 1,...N$ then

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} (\overline{t} - t_i)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N} (t_{\max}-t_i)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N} t_{\max}^2 = N t_{\max}^2$$

Comment: With $t_i = \frac{1}{i}$ we have $t_{max} = 1$ and $\bar t = \frac{1}{N} H_n$, where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number. As $N \rightarrow \infty$, $\bar t \rightarrow 0$ so the sum of differences tends to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ which exceeds ${t_{max}}^2 = 1$. So for sufficiently large $N$, we must have a counter example to the claim for positive $t_i$.

Comment: I just check $N = 100$ and got $1.365895...$ for the sum of differences, so the claim doesn't hold.

Comment: I don't think it would hold even if we require $t_i \ge k$, since $t_i = \frac{1}{i} + k$ looks like a counter example. I think the only possible revision is to require $t_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: @Babado : yes, sorry, forgot to mention, $t_i \ge 0, \forall i \in [1,N]$. I will edit the post.

Comment: @user6376297 Are the $t_i$ integers? If not, I have already given a counter example above.

Comment: @ThomasKing : no, they are real numbers. I am confused now, some people seem to have proven that the inequality holds, and you are saying it might not :S

Comment: @user6376297 no one here has proven your original inequality, only related inequalities; I think your original inequality may hold when restricting the $t_i$ to natural numbers, but I am not sure why

Comment: @ThomasKing : you're right, sorry. Usually in our data $t_{min} = 0$. I didn't know the standard deviation was bound to the range of the data, so that's already very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the standard deviation of the $t_i$ is at most the range $r = t_{max} - t_{min}$,

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (t_i - \bar t)^2 \le r^2$$

and therefore,

$$\sum_{i=1}^N (t_i - \bar t)^2 \le N r^2$$

This holds for any $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Edit**:
Your inequality is that

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (t_i - \bar t)^2 \le \frac{r^2}{N}$$

Consider $N = 6$,

\begin{cases} 
 t_i = 0 & 1 \le i \le 3 \\
 t_i = 1 & 3\lt i \le 6
\end{cases}

Then $r = 1$, $\bar t = \frac{1}{2}$ and the variance is $\frac{1}{4}$. But $\frac{1}{4} \gt \frac{1}{6}$ so your inequality does not hold.

It also doesn't hold for distinct $t_i \in \mathbb{N}$, since $N = 10$ and $t_i = i$ is a counter example.